# Is thttpd still alive?

Tags: thttpd

is the thttpd webserver project still alive?  Should this sever be used for a new project?  The latest release looks like it was in December of 03 and the mailing list archive stops in may of 08.

Answer (score 6):

You may have a better luck at [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) or [cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/). They are light & fast web servers, and they are also being actively developed.

Answer (score 5):

I could find no info that pointed to any active development in a long time, so I would not use it to start a new project.

My suggestion would be [nginx](http://nginx.net/), which is quite popular, light, fast and actively developed. Yes, the homepage doesn't look like much, but the product is currently used to serve or proxy about 3-4% of websites worldwide, making it more popular than lighttpd.

The main advantage of thttpd seems to be the output throttling. It's still unique in its implementation, but nginx has a [module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpLimitReqModule) that comes close.

Comment: +1 for nginx. thttpd is indead dead.